# I can't seem to run ngAnimate?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ngAnimate dependency injection problem. I'm not sure why, but whenever I include ngAnimate as a dependence inside my js code it doesn't work... 
it's not the script...

I have this html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
        <head>


            <script src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script>

            <script src="codebuttonewb.js"></script>

            <style>
                    .hidden{
                        display:none;
                    }
                    ul{
                    //display:flex;
                    margin-bottom:10px;
                     list-style-type: none;
                    }
                    li span{
                    display:inline-block;
                    line-height:50px;

                    }
                    li img{
                    margin-right:10px;
                    border-radius:50%;
                    width:50px;
                    height:50px;
                    }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body ng-controller="myController">
            <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="search">
            <ul ng-class="{'hidden' : !toggle}"><!--  if this value is false then show the class of hidden -->
                <li ng-repeat="item in list | filter:search"
                    ng-class="item.age>29 ? 'over-thirty' : 'under-thirty'">

                    <img ng-src="{{item.img}}"/>
                    <span> {{item.name}} - <em>{{item.age}}</em></span>
                </li>

            </ul>
            <button ng-show="!toggle" ng-click="toggle=true" >show names</button>
            <button  ng-show="toggle" ng-click="toggle=false">hide names</button>
            <form ng-submit="addPerson()">

                    <input type="text" placeholder="name" ng-model="name"/>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="number" placeholder="age" ng-model="age"/>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" />

                </form>

        </body>

</html>
```

and this js code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate'])
            .controller("myController",function($scope){


                $scope.toggle =true; 


                $scope.list=[
                {name:'bla',age:28,img: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brad_frost/128.jpg'},
                {name:'blabla',age:38,img: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/mlane/128.jpg'},
                {name:'blaba',age:23, img:'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/felipenogs/128.jpg'},
                {name:'blablala',age:56, img:'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adellecharles/128.jpg'}
                ];


                $scope.addPerson= function(){
                    $scope.list.push({name:$scope.name,age:$scope.age});
                    $scope.name="";
                    $scope.age="";
                };
            });
```

Any solution would be more than welcome. It's my first time using ngAnimate so I guess it's probably something dumb.

Comment: I don;t see any issue here http://plnkr.co/edit/c0JhEjQUro41eiaOP2Nu?p=preview .. could you please reproduce it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into similar issues before. Try changing:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="https//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script>

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script> (https://)

Answer (score 0):

to use ngAnimate you need to add any CSS effect with it. 
Let me suggest you some animation-css methods.

```
<div class="fade"></div>
<style>
/* The starting CSS styles for the enter animation */
.fade.ng-enter {
  transition:0.5s linear all;
  opacity:0;
}

/* The finishing CSS styles for the enter animation */
.fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}
</style>
```

ngAnimate will onlye enter **ng-enter** and **ng-active** class. You need to write css your own. Here i have given fade effect.